# isVoiceInteraction is always return false in action MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH

Tags: android, voice

I want to handle voice interactions with search music in my app.

I've tried to add intent action filter `android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH`
and category `android.intent.category.VOICE` and `android.intent.category.DEFAULT`
but I don't known why `isVoiceInteraction` function always returns `false`
it works if action is `android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE` so I think it`s a bug?